# Highlighting rows with trailing and leading space/s

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to highlight rows with trailing and leading spaces. I've below query but want to know if there is better more efficient way to achieve this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM DummyTable lc 
WHERE 
    (lc.Code LIKE '% ' OR lc.Code LIKE ' %' or lc.Code like '%  % %' OR lc.Code like '% %  %') 
    AND (lc.StartDate <= getdate() AND lc.EndDate > getdate()) 
    AND (lc.CodeTypeID <> 27) 
ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

Please note that I don't want to remove space from the field "Code" but just highlight in my result set.

Comment: Your code is also looking for multiple spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use string functions `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` to check if the string starts or ends with a space, like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DummyTable 
WHERE 
    (LEFT(Code, 1) = ' ' OR RIGHT(Code, 1) = ' ')
    AND StartDate <= getdate()
    AND EndDate > getdate()
    AND CodeTypeID <> 27 
ORDER BY 4 desc
```

As commented by Martin Smith, `(LEFT(Code, 1) = ' ' OR RIGHT(Code, 1) = ' ')` can be simplified as `' ' IN (LEFT(Code, 1), RIGHT(Code, 1))`.

NB: few simplifications in your query:

- you don't need to prefix the columns with the table name, since only one table is involved in the query
- you don't need to surround individual conditions with parenthesis (just make sure to surround the `OR`ed conditions with parenthesis to separate them from the `AND`ed conditions

Comment: thanks @GMB. would above capture multiple trailing or leading spaces? or its just single space?

Comment: @ZulfiqarDholkawala: at least one trailing or leading space

Answer (score 1):

There is not a more efficient method, but you can reduce the number of comparisons:

```
WHERE CONCAT(' ', lc.Code, ' ') LIKE '%  %' AND
      lc.StartDate <= getdate() AND
      lc.EndDate > getdate() AND
      lc.CodeTypeID <> 27
```

This adds a space to the beginning and end and then looks for two spaces in a row (which seems to be your intention despite how the question is phrased).

Unfortunately, there is little you can do to improve performance beause all the comparisons are inequalities.